# Bootstrap Navbar Issue with getting button to pull right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get my navbar buttons to line up on the right side.

I have tried:
class="pull-right" && "text-right"

I have also tried:
.btn-talent{
align-items: right
}

I am struggling.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

I also put this in a codepen:

[https://codepen.io/rob-connolly/pen/yLaGMyW[enter](https://codepen.io/rob-connolly/pen/yLaGMyW%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Ooe.png)

```css
.btn-investors {
  background: #029D89;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 4vw;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-talent {
  background: #029D89;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 4vw;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>meetlete: meet your favorite athletes!</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Paytone+One&family=Questrial&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/images/favicon.png" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <!-- --- Navbar Issue --  -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://meetlete.com">
      <img src="./assets/images/meetlete-logo.png" width="200px" alt="Meetlete Logo">
    </a>

    <!-- btn one issue -->

    <a href="./investor.html"><button class="btn btn-talent" type="button">Talent</button></a>

    <!-- btn two issue -->
    <a href="./investor.html"><button class="btn btn-investors" type="button">Investors</button></a>
  </nav>










  <!-- Content -->


  <!-- Footer -->

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="container-flex bg-footerTop text-center text-lg-start">
    <!-- Grid container -->
    <div class="p-4">
      <!--Grid row-->
      <div class="row">
        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-md-0">
          <h5 class="text-uppercase">About Us</h5>

          <p>
            Meetlete wants to give you the once in a lifetime opportunity to meet one of your favorite athletes. We are the first platform that allows fans to have personal one on one video calls with the biggest stars in sports. With every meetlete video call, we
            donate a portion of the proceeds to the foundation of the athlete's choice. What makes this possible is the Meetlete secure and private platform. <br><br>Launching 2/14/21! <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
          </p>
        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->

        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
          <h5 class="text-uppercase">Address:</h5>
          <span>Meetlete, Inc.<br>
            Po Box 294<br>
            La Mesa, CA 91944
        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->

        <!--Grid column-->
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
          <h5 class="text-uppercase mb-0">Links</h5>

          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <a href="./talent.html" class="text-dark">Talent Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="./fans.html" class="text-dark">Fans Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="./investor.html" class="text-dark">Investor Info</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="mailto: rob@meetlete.com" class="text-dark">Press</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--Grid column-->
      </div>
      <!--Grid row-->
    </div>
    <!-- Grid container -->

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center p-3 copyright" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
      © 2020 Copyright:
      <a class="text-dark" href="https://meetlete.com">Meetlete.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </footer>
  <!-- Footer -->

  <!-- bootstrap js file-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

.

Comment: `pull-right` is for bootstrap3. It's `float-right` in bootstrap4.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your buttons with `div`. `.navbar` is a flexbox and uses `justify: space-between` rule. Here the buttons are flexbox items that's why they are spread inside `nav`.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://meetlete.com">
      <img src="./assets/images/meetlete-logo.png" width="200px" alt="Meetlete Logo">
    </a>

    <div>
       <a href="./investor.html"><button class="btn btn-talent" type="button">Talent</button></a>

       <a href="./investor.html"><button class="btn btn-investors" type="button">Investors</button></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```